# Проверка на вход в диапазон

Tags: django, python-3.5, django-orm

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
В модели имеются такие поля

```
class Tariffs(models.Model):
    days = IntegerRangeField(verbose_name=u'Дни')
    rate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=u'Коэффициент', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

В базе содержаться записи days разных диапазонов (например (0, 7)) и коэффциенты (rate) . Я получаю от пользователя две даты, вычисляю между ними количество дней и хочу проверить в какой диапазон из полей попадает это число, далее если найдено умножить на соответствующий коэффициент и потом уже вывести. 
Как примерно действовать? Использую Django 1.10.
 
Про QuerySet, фильтры и т.д читал, просто не могу понять, как примерно должен выглядить запрос. 

 Спасибо за любые наводки.

Comment: Вопроса так и не понял. Какой запрос вы хотите составить?

Comment: @МистерФикс В базе поля с типами данных int4range (days) и decimal(rate). Получаю от пользователя количество дней и нужно сходить в базу посмотреть в какой диапазон этот день попадает и умножить на соответствующий коэффициент. Например: пользователь ввел две даты, я вычислил разницу получил 9 дней. В базе есть интервалы (0-7) с коэф. 2, (8-14) с коэф. 2.2, (15-24) с коэф. 3.2 и т.д. Получается 9 попадает в (8-14) - умножаем на 2.2, получаем 19.8. Надеюсь объяснил )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У PostgreSQL имеются [диапазонные функции](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/functions-range). 
 Мне нужно было проверить, в какой диапазон входит число (day). Для этого, как раз подходит оператор 'содержит элемент' `@>`.
 В SQL выглядит так `SELECT day FROM tariffs WHERE days @> day`. (где `day = request.GET['day']`, получаю от пользователя, в данном случае через GET; days имеет диапазонный тип `int4range`)
  
 Через Django ORM получается так 
 query = `Tariffs.objects.filter(days__contains=day).values('rate')`. Так я нашел нужный коэффициент.